# Is it possible to automatically advance the date and time contained in a MySQL column every time a specific period of time elapses

Tags: mysql, datetime

First of all, sorry if I make mistakes or have a hard time explaining, I'm not used to working with MySQL as that is not my position, but our database developer is being slightly stubborn so I have to ask this question.

Is it possible to advance the time and date stored in a column by let's say a week after every week elapses.

I'm building an Android application that will depend on a schedule, there will be a few initial dates in the MySQL database and some of those will signify actions that need to be perform every week, others every two weeks and some every month.

It will display the timetable in a basic list contained in a RecyclerView in Android studio.

Now, of course I could just snatch the initial date from the database and then just create intervals, but that would complicate the code possibly needlessly since I would have to always check and discard those dates that have already passed.

If there was a way to update the MySQL database at certain intervals that would make my life a whole lot easier.

I could just make the code snatch the available dates from the server, organize the cards in RecyclerView by date and then onwards and upwards.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and my apologies if I have been unclear.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I wouldn't recommend advancing the date time after specific intervals. I have no idea how much of record you are having in your database, but these will drastically impact the performance of the database.

Technically, it is feasible by creating a crons job to do execute a certain query to advance the date time value in your column. Be sure to specify the condition to only update the required records.

Other than crons job to advance the date time value, you can embed your logic in your application to get the interval / elapsed time by subtracting today date and the initial date. Then you can specify what are your actions depending on the elapsed time. If you need to know what actions have been occurred to a record, you can create an additional table to store the transactional actions to a record (pretty much like a audit/log table). Be sure to prune the table from time to time if you have large transactional actions in order to keep the database performance at optimum.

Comment: Hi Wen,
Thank you for your response.

I might have expressed awkwardly and have edited my post so that I don't confuse future readers.

It's a schedule, writing elapsed time was my mistake and made it appear as if I was tracking back time, when in essence what I need to know is what's the next date the event will occur at (i.e. initial date was FRI 15.02 and the subsequent should be 22.02.)

The contractor hasn't delivered us the list of data for the database, but it should contain about 600 entries containing about 20 columns in total.

I think the app might look at 200-1000 users.

Comment: @StuartMcGinley Could you check whether MySQL Event Scheduler is able to the job? It allows you to set job in MySQL and run at a specific interval. Without understand the actual requirement and design, it would be impossible for me to suggest the right solution.